# How exactly do I extract and merge a audio file using @ffmpeg/ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, multipartform-data, multer-s3

I have a lot of issues about audio transfer to server and frontend.

I am building a solution that is extracting and merging a file received from frontend.

I am using local ffmpeg file with node.js child_process package.

My Env:

framework: nest.js

runtime: node.js

lang: typescript

here is console.log(file: Express.Multer.File).
I am storing to S3 bucket these files. So I am not using multer's memory, disk storage.

```
// console.log(file);
 {
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'input1.mp3',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'audio/mpeg'
}
```

```
import cp from "child_process";

type Section = { from: number, to: number };

const files: Array<Express.Multer.File> = [];

export const setupAudioFileSection = async (file: Express.Multer.File, section: Section) => {
  try {
    const file1 = await cp.exec(`ffmpeg -i ${file} -y -ss 0 -t ${section.from}`);
    const file2 = await cp.exec(`ffmpeg -i ${file} -y -ss ${section.from} -t ${section.to}`);
    const file3 = await cp.exec(`ffmpeg -i ${file} -y -ss ${section.to}`);
    files.push(file1);
    files.push(file3);

    return file2;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error('setupAudioFileSection error');
  }
```

But, My Local ffmpeg is printing the error. because of [object Object]. I think local ffmpeg is not recognized the audio file received from client. So, I am resolving this issue by writing a file to disk or memory directly. but I am confusing this solution whether is right or not.

```
error Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -i [object Object] -y -ss 10 -t 20 -f mp3 ./TestOutput
ffmpeg version 5.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100

[object: No such file or directory
```

How can I write file on my server and read? if that can be, I can resolve [object Object] of ffmpeg issue maybe. Please some answer or advise my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Before commenting, I suggest you ask one question by one post. Every coder meet many errors to debug and such erros can be solved one by one.

Comment: You have [object Object] logs for the error. [object Object] is a form of object without `stringify`. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(targetObject))`. In the case `targetObject` would be `file` I guess. When logging objects should be stringified. I attach [a related reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)